# public IP address assignment upon hosting (IP v4 shortage)

Tags: firebase, networking, dns, ip, firebase-hosting

How public IP assignment works while deploying an app to hosting?
When I deploy my static site to Firebase, I receive domain of that site and can reach it through the browser as any other site. If I ping that domain I'll get public IP address of that domain.
**The question is:**
What is the mechanism of giving that IP to me? Firebase having some quota on that IPs? I mean there is a shortage of public IPs v4, but still I can deploy many apps for free (and get IP for each) as others do. Or there is some mechanism which somehow does not influence the shortage of IPs v4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting is a shared hosting service, typically hosting many sites on each server (and hosting each site on many servers on its worldwide CDN network).

This means that many sites are going to be using that same IP address that your site is using, but they can be distinguished because they each have a unique domain name.